# Irreducible representatin of $\mathfrak{so}_{p,q}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Consider the real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_{p,q}$, is there a way to classify the irreducible representations of this algebra in $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$?

For example the $ad$ representation is given by,

$$
[\Delta_{i,j} ; Y_k] = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
        -Y_j & \text{if}\ k = i  \\
        \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_j}Y_i &\text{if}\ k=j
    \end{array}\right.
$$

where $\Delta_{i,j}$ is the standart basis for $\mathfrak{so}_{p,q}$ (if needed I can give it in term of elementary matrices), $\alpha_i=1$ when $1\leq i\leq p$ and $\alpha_i=-1$ when $p+1\leq i\leq p+q$ and $(Y_1,\cdots,Y_{p+q})$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$.

It is an irreducible representation, does any non equivalent irreducible representation exists ?

Thank you!

Comment: In your penultimate line, do you mean any non-equivalent *irreducible* representation in $\mathbb R^{p+q}$ (because otherwise, for starters, there's the trivial one)? -- Why do you call that "the $ad$ representation"? That's confusing because it is not what is usually called the adjoint representation. -- Have you tried the dual, that's a standard candidate for a representation of the same dimension which sometimes is non-isomorphic? -- What have you tried from representation theory, e.g. looking at complex irreps of the complexified Lie algebra?

Comment: yes I meant _irreducible_ representations, I update the text accordingly. 
Thank you for your hints, I will try the dual representation.I am quiet new to representation theory so I didn't get really the point of classification for now. 
for the complexified Lie algebra, my question can be: what are the irreps of $\mathfrak{so}_n(\Bbb C)$ in $\Bbb C^n$ (we can assume $n\geq 3$) ?

Comment: Well that should be covered by classical "highest-weight" representation theory of Lie algebras. I think Fulton-Harris has an entire chapter on the special orthogonal group/algebra. An excellent source is https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/deligne.pdf, some basic facts are in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_representation#Spin_representations_and_their_weights. Don't panic, you are focussing on a very special case and will not need all the information in there.